# Limit formula for the second derivative

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a real-valued function which is twice differentiable in the interval $(-1,1)$. Does the following hold?:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - 2f(0) + f(-h)}{h^2} = f''(0)$$

If $f''(x)$ is continuous this follows from Taylor's theorem with the
Lagrange form of the remainder.  What if $f''(x)$ is not continuous?
-- Thanks.

Comment: how can it be discontinuous when it is differentiable?

Comment: I don't understand @CarloBeenakker's comment: of course it's perfectly possible for $f$ to be twice differentiable but for $f''$ to be discontinuous. Nevertheless, the question isn't appropriate for this forum. I'd suggest asking on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: apologies, I missread f for f''.

Comment: Hey guys, please check whether this question is nontrivial or not before deciding to shut it down. I may make a meta post in the reopening thread. (BTW, it seems the poster is in fact a professional mathematician.)

Comment: I think this follows directly from the "Peano form of remainder" appearing [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) on Wikipedia, which does not require continuity of the $k$th derivative.

Comment: @NateEldredge I must confess I couldn't answer the question here, because I'd forgotten the Peano remainder version of Taylor expansion. Armed with those magic words, some searching led to https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/taylors-theorem-with-the-lagrange-form-of-the-remainder/ which closes with the calculation to show that the answer to the OP's question is positive

Comment: (Incidentally, @ToddTrimble, I was a bit amused by your use of "in fact" since it goes to show once again that Well Known Names in some areas aren't at all known in others. Which is just the way of life, of course.)

Comment: Gowers shows something slightly different, but the trick is the same: write down the Taylor approximations near 0 for $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$, then add them.

Comment: @YemonChoi I don't understand why that's amusing, but okay.

Comment: While I can see the possible rationale for deletion, it would be nice if some of the commenters above or those voting for deletion had a look at http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=218905

Comment: I see that I was wrong in voting to close, I have voted to reopen. I clearly misjudged the depth of the question (partly influenced, I have to confess, by the poor formatting and absence of motivating explanation).

Answer (score 6):

Just so an answer is put here rather than in the comments:

As noted in the original question, the desired limit formula is a well-known, or at least straightforward, consequence of Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder **in cases where $f\in C^2$**, i.e. if we have some continuity of the 2nd derivative in a neighbourhood of $0$.

As pointed out by Nate Eldredge in the comments: for functions which are merely twice differentiable at the origin, i.e. where the second derivative exists at $0$ but might not be continuous in a neighbourhood of $0$, one still has Taylor's theorem (of order $2$) with [*Peano remainder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem):
$$
f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2 + h(x)x^2
$$
where $h(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. This is enough to obtain the desired limit formula.

*Remark.* I took the liberty of contacting the OP and he said:

> I am teaching the first real analysis course
>   for math majors.  In class I
>   proved that if you know the value of a twice
>   differentiable function at three points you
>   know the value of the second derivative at
>   some point ... and I assumed you need continuity
>   of the second derivative to prove the
>   limit formula.